# bulk email sender using Amazon SES can't add "List-Unsubscribe" header to sending email

Tags: amazon-ses, amazon-sesv2

Here is for you to send bulk emails using the methods, `SendBulkTemplatedEmail`, `SendTemplatedEmail` or `SendEmail` (`send_bulk_templated_email`, `send_templated_email` or `send_email`), on Amazon SES.

---

In "Email sender guidelines" on Google and Yahoo, bulk email sender need to implement the requirements below.

- [Requirements for sending 5,000 or more messages per day](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?visit_id=638416590663890276-2292961685&rd=1&hl=en&sjid=11361266357807161227-AP#requirements-5k)

In the requirements, there is a requirement that bulk email sender need to add "List-Unsubscribe" header to sending email.

- [Make it easy to unsubscribe](https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126?visit_id=638416590663890276-2292961685&rd=1&hl=en&sjid=11361266357807161227-AP#subscriptions)

The requirement has -

- Add "List-Unsubscribe" header to sending email.

If you send bulk email using the methods, `SendBulkTemplatedEmail`, `SendTemplatedEmail` or `SendEmail`, on Amazon SES, you can't add "List-Unsubscribe" header to sending email for now.